# 2010 version of the splist

Tags: list

Does anyone have 2010 version of this codeplex feature? It's call SPListDisplaySetting. https://splistdisplaysetting.codeplex.com. We have so many HR forms that are micro managed which group can see and edit particular fields in a list.

I WOULD TRULY TRULY APPRECIATED if someone would share 2010 version of this feature.

Comment: I've tried running the solution onto a SharePoint 2010 farm and got a System.Exception error with no details upon installation. Even tried extracting the .wsp from MSI without success. At this cannot help more, later will try to recompile!

Comment: @C.Marius: Thanks for helping me out. I was able to get hold of the wsp and manually install it (with powershell) but it wont deploy. It at "Deploying" status for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks pretty much like the one you posted.

http://sppex.codeplex.com/ I haven't tried it but eager to try. I will let you know how my testing went in dev.

However, I would like to know if anyone here ever tried this and their experience.

Edited: I did a test with Infopath and infopath does not respect the fields setting by this feature.

It works with ootb forms (newform, edit form, etc.)